# Lua Coroutines resume : bad argument #-1 to 'resume' (expected bool)

Tags: lua

I'm kind of very new to lua and just inherited a lua code base where I see an error happening occasionally on resuming a coroutines

```
--coroutine creation
self._active_test_worker =
        coroutine.create(function(timestep)
            return self._active_test:worker(timestep)
        end)

--coroutine resume 
local temp = type(self._active_test_worker) //thread
local temp2 = type(timestep) // number
local statsu = coroutine.status(self._active_test_worker) // suspended
local success,action = coroutine.resume(self._active_test_worker, timestep)
```

The 'resume' function raises the following error intermittently

```
factory.lua:478: bad argument #-1 to 'resume' (expected bool)
```

Can someone please help me in understanding the error? What is argument -1? ( what does negative mean here?) What might raise this error? I couldn't find much online or in the docs about this error. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: That error message does not come from the Lua core.

Comment: I only found this section having mentioned an `argument -1`: https://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html, look at the bottom section. What type of Lua environment are you working in?

Comment: Two things:  1. If it's intermittent, this smells of a race condition somewhere.  I'd double-check to make sure that self._active_test_worker is a valid value before calling resume.  2. resume() both starts a coroutine and resumes it after it's yield()ed, so maybe double-check which case it is (was this at initial run time, or some time later?).